# How to use google maps engine connector?

Tags: qgis, google-maps, imagery

I am trying to use google imagery in QGIS through the Google maps engine connector plugin.  I relatively new to QGIS and need some help.  What I want to do i use the google maps in QGIS and then print them on a custom 3ft by 3ft map for a client.  Is this possible with the plug in?  Also if it is how do I get it to work.  I have established an API as directed but now I am stuck.

Is there anymore step by step documentation on how to use the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/using_gme_connector.html:

```
Warning

As of 29 January, 2015 Google Maps Engine has stopped creation of new free accounts. If you already have a Maps Engine account, the Google Maps Engine Connector will continue to work till 29 January, 2016.
```

https://mapsengine.google.com/about/index.html has yet another discontinue message.

So it seems the plugin is not useful anymore. You may as well contact the author about it.